# Unable to find object scatter addon in blender 2.9

Tags: objects, 3d-view, add-on, customization

I recently upgraded to blender 2.9. Though I have enabled Object-scatter addon, I couldn't find it using the search(f3) in the viewport. Where can I find that addon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out that just enabling Developers extra works. For anyone else experiencing the same issue go to Edit > Preferences > Interface and tick the developers extra